# Computer won't power on

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply

Was working fine for over a year, now won't boot. LEDs on the GFX card and one on the MOBO labeled PWR glow when plugged in, but nothing happens when I push power and shorting switch pins does nothing either. If I pop out the CMOS battery and put it back in then try the fans lurch but nothing happens. Shorting the 15 and 16 pins turns the PSU on, and when the 24pin connector is attached to the MOBO it will start up briefly then stop. If I plug in the CPU header it returns to what I described, no power but will lurch after replacing the CMOS battery. Should I be shopping for a new PSU or is there another problem maybe?

Comment: See if you can test it with another PSU that you know is in good working condition.

Comment: Yeah I'm planning to when I can, just have none around at the moment.